# HttpActionContext gave an error message in a method

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I upgraded a webapi in .net framework 4.6 to 8.0 web api core today and I got the error message
below from the IsAuthorized method

"The type or namespace name 'HttpActionContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

```
        public class CustomApiAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
            [Inject]

            public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { private get; set; }
         
            protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
            {
                var principal = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;

                if (!principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

                    return false;

                return UnitOfWork.IsUserAuthorized(principal.Identity.Name.Substring(5));
            }
        }
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: It seems you don't accept answers very often, this way discourages others from helping you. if the answer helps you, better accept it as the answer

Comment: I'm sorry. I accept answers that work for me so i don't mislead others. The answer provided does not work for me. HttpContext.User.Identity is always null and not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same goal by utilizing filters

something similar to this :

```
public class CustomApiAuthorizeAttribute :Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        if(context.HttpContext.User.Identity != null && context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // do your work
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test though

Comment: This does not work for me. HttpContext.User.Identity is always null